# (Py)Qt - QTreeView, Model, insert row

Tags: qt, treeview, pyqt

I am little bit confuse.
I am working with QTreeView as model I assigned QSortFilterProxyModel.
http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/qsortfilterproxymodel.html

```
//treeview
self.ProxyView = QtGui.QTreeView(self.centralwidget)

//model
self.ProxyModel = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
self.ProxyModel.setSourceModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel(0, 3, self))

//assign model to tree
self.ProxyView.setModel(self.ProxyModel)
```

On button click I want to add row to this tree.

Here is my slot
    def pushButton_addRow(self):
        self.ProxyModel.insertRow(0)
        self.ProxyModel.setData(self.ProxyModel.index(0,0), "hi")

It doesnt work, it works only for first row, then I added empty rows. But wenn I fill second cell it works.

```
self.ProxyModel.setData(self.ProxyModel.index(0,1), "hi")
```

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your new QModelIndex has wrong parent()?